Is there a better way to cleanup text files with Python, using regex?
I'm trying to create a script to match regex patterns in a series of text files, and the remove those matches from the file.  Right now, I have the following, which works for my purposes, but I don't think this is an effective way to do it:
import os
import re

os.chdir("/home/user1/test_files")

patterns = ['(bannana)',
            '(peaches)',
            '(apples)'
           ]

subst = ""
cwd = os.getcwd()
for filename in os.listdir(cwd):
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
        file = f.read()
    result = re.sub('|'.join(patterns), subst, file, re.MULTILINE)
    with open("/home/user1/output_files/" + "output_" + str(filename), 'w', encoding="utf-8") as newfile:
        newfile.write(result)

    for pattern in patterns:
        with open('/home/user1/output_files/output_'+str(filename), 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
            file = f.read()
        result = re.sub(pattern, subst, file, re.MULTILINE)
        with open('/home/user1/output_files/output_'+str(filename), 'w', encoding="utf-8") as newfile:
            newfile.write(result)

So, lets say I have a file, grocery.txt, and I want to remove the words apples, peaches, and bannana.  The above script will first run through and create an output file, output_grocery.txt.  It will then iterate through the patterns list, removing the pattern from output_grocery.txt and rewriting it after each pass.
The way I'm doing this right now is not scalable.  I'll eventually need to run this on hundreds of files, each one being rewritten again and again depending on how many regex patterns I have.  I originally tried doing this in one go, using:
result = re.sub('|'.join(patterns), subst, file, re.MULTILINE)

thinking that would remove all the patterns in one go from the file.  However, this only removes the first pattern, in this case bannana.
Is there a better, more scalable way to do this?

At the very least you could open the input file once and load into your file variable, then iterate on that file variable to clean the contents, then write it out when you are done. Once.

Please make a [mre] including example input, expected output, and code that we can run (like to start, I don't have /home/user1 on my system, so that os.chdir() will fail).

Why are you writing it to file after each pattern?

BTW, this is totally irrelevant to the problem, but it's better to give a name to any values you use more than once, like '/home/user1/output_files/output_' and 'utf8'. Good names could be, say, OUTPUT_DIR and ENCODING. Cf magic numbers: Wikipedia, SO

"However, this only removes the first pattern" - I just tried the code for myself but I can't reproduce that behaviour, but then, I had to guess at what the data could be.

Expanding on my comment. While there are likely improvements to be made to this, you should at the very least only open the input once, clean up the data, and then write the data out once. None of  the open/write/open/write/open/write/open/write stuff
import os
import re

os.chdir("/home/user1/test_files")

patterns = ['(bannana)',
            '(peaches)',
            '(apples)'
           ]

subst = ""
cwd = os.getcwd()
for filename in os.listdir(cwd):

    #open the file and place contents in `file` variable
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
        file = f.read()

    #iterate over your patterns, replacing the pattern with 
    #nothing and updating the `file` variable for the next 
    #pattern iteration
    for pattern in patterns:
        file = re.sub(pattern, subst, file, re.MULTILINE)

    #write the `file` variable back out
    with open("/home/user1/output_files/" + "output_" + str(filename), 'w', encoding="utf-8") as newfile:
        newfile.write(file)

Now that the logic is isolated, you can work on improving that that for pattern in patterns to not be a loop to gain extra efficiency.

check your name assignments.

thx @GeneBurinsky. Fixed

This is  perfect.  There's an immediate improvement in completion time.  Thanks!

This:
patterns = ["(banana)", "(apples)", "(peaches)"]
result = re.sub("|".join(patterns), "", "xxbananaxxapplesxxpeachesxx")

will return xxxxxxxx. So joining the strings to a pattern in this way is not the problem. How do your real patterns look like? re.MULTILINE affects what $ and ^ do, which indicates that you use one of those, perhaps you use them in a way that would explain why it only replaces the first occurrence?
